# Permanent metadata for videos

Tags: video-capture, formats, metadata

Is there any existing container (video format) in which the metadata is immutable?
I am new to this topic and my use case is that once a video is recorded, I want to preserve the metadata (for ex location, time, some caption used while sharing it, etc) in such a way that no one can alter this information, or worst case, only the original creator can do so.

Comment: Can’t think of one, but there really should be.  Photographers have been asking camera manufacturers for ages to build encryption into cameras to help protect their IP. Immutable metadata/self destructing tamperproof files or blockchain custody ledgers would all empower creators.

Answer (score 1):

Containers don't support encryption of metadata, and without encryption everyone may change what he wants (even damaging by his action the whole multimedia file).

There is a possibility to make a checksum of your file (as SHA-256), but it will not protect to change it, it only helps detect if the file is in its original state (not changed).

Answer (score 0):

No.  Metadata can always be changed. Even if there isn't a commonly known program to do so, an experienced person could always hex edit the file.